# como utilizar o sharedpreferences

Tags: php, json, sharedpreferences

Boa Tarde será que alguém pode me dar um exemplo de como criar o sharedpreferences... eu estou em uma  situação ruim onde .. eu valido o usuário e senha no servidor utilizando php via webservice e após a validação eu preciso mostrar ao usuario as suas empresas cadastradas.... mas quando eu realizo o SELECT via web service novamente retornando uma json .. ele me retorna tudo que ha no banco de dados segue o exemplo.

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT UC, Instalacao, Nome_Logo FROM Tab_UC ") or die('Could not query');
```

Porém eu preciso que esse SELECT me retorne apenas a UC, Instalação e Nome_Logo do usuário logado e não de todos os usuário cadastrados... eu preciso de um exemplo pra ver como funciona.

Comment: Olá @Ortolano seria interessante você dá uma passado no tour do site para conhecer um pouquinho mais sobre o StackOverflow. Segue:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Seu problema é que você não filtra os dados para ser apenas do usuário logado. Você tem que fazer o select filtrando pelo id, nome, email ou qualquer outra coisa do usuário logado.